# Complicated MySQL Join - Sender/Recipient and Recipient/Sender

Tags: mysql

I have a database table that holds text messages like this (simplified):

**Sample Data**

```
id     sender         recipient        content
_____________________________________________________________________
1      15555551111    15555552222      Hello from 1111 to 2222
2      15555552222    15555551111      Hello from 2222 to 1111
3      15555553333    15555551111      Hello from 3333 to 1111
4      15555551111    15555554444      Hello from 1111 to 4444
5      15555551111    15555552222      It's me again
6      15555554444    15555551111      Hey 1111, it's 4444
```

What I would like is to query all the messages together to show the latest message between two phone numbers, regardless of who sends/receives the message, sort of like how your cell phone groups text messages together. For example, I'd like to query and end up with the following results, sorted by most recent first:

**Desired Query Results**

```
id     sender         recipient        content
_____________________________________________________________________
6      15555554444    15555551111      Hey 1111, it's 4444 
5      15555551111    15555552222      It's me again   
3      15555553333    15555551111      Hello from 3333 to 1111
```

I admit I'm scratching my head on how to do this, but I think I need some sort of advanced join to include the latest message from each set of phone numbers, regardless of who sent/received it. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**SQL DEMO**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sBtWRrGX1vbLG8FFAu5EL2/0)

You can get the last id between 2 numbers like this:

```
SELECT MAX(id),
       LEAST(sender, recipient),
       GREATEST(sender, recipient)           
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY LEAST(sender, recipient), 
         GREATEST(sender, recipient)
```

Then to get the latest messages:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE id IN (    
    SELECT MAX(id) 
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY LEAST(sender, recipient), 
             GREATEST(sender, recipient)
)
```

Comment: Thank you! Not only were you the first one to respond with exactly what I was looking for, but your query also performs the best when scaled up to hundreds of thousands of rows. You're my hero!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with NOT EXISTS:

```
select t.*
from tablename t
where not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where 
    least(sender, recipient) = least(t.sender, t.recipient)
    and 
    greatest(sender, recipient) = greatest(t.sender, t.recipient)
    and 
    id > t.id
);
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9tEQp7NK2tP9H7BTgeseaw/0).
Results:

```
| id  | sender      | recipient   | content                 |
| --- | ----------- | ----------- | ----------------------- |
| 3   | 15555553333 | 15555551111 | Hello from 3333 to 1111 |
| 5   | 15555551111 | 15555552222 | It's me again           |
| 6   | 15555554444 | 15555551111 | Hey 1111, it's 4444     |
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I tried out your query, but Juan Carlos Oropeza's response performed better with my data.